# Can I verify what algo php session hashing is using?

Tags: php, session, hash

I'm trying to make sure I'm using sha512 for session hashing. When I print out my algos I get

```
Array
(
[0] => md2
[1] => md4
[2] => md5
[3] => sha1
[4] => sha224
[5] => sha256
[6] => sha384
[7] => sha512 
[8] => ripemd128
etc....
)
```

So in php.ini I set it like,

```
session.hash_function = 7
```

The only reason i'm confused is that in the .ini file it lists hashing schemes differently than what php prints, for example 0 as md5 not md2.

```
; Select a hash function
; 0: MD5   (128 bits)
; 1: SHA-1 (160 bits)
```

Is this just the default hashing schemes for maybe an older php version or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0` and `1` are the only numeric values that are [actually documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function):

> session.hash_function allows you to
>   specify the hash algorithm used to
>   generate the session IDs. '0' means
>   MD5 (128 bits) and '1' means SHA-1
>   (160 bits).

If you want to leverage other algorithms:

> Since PHP 5.3.0 it is also possible to
>   specify any of the algorithms provided
>   by the hash extension (if it is
>   available), like sha512 or whirlpool.
>   A complete list of supported
>   algorithms can be obtained with the
>   hash_algos() function.

I admit it's not clearly expressed, but the definition of the directive states that its argument is of `mixed` type. It expects either an integer (for MD5 and SHA-1 only) or the *name* (string) of the algorithm as returned by [hash_algos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php). (Incidentally, that also means that there're two ways to specify MD5 and SHA-1.) Developers changed their mind when new algorithms were added but kept backwards compatibility.

I've tried this code and I got a huge session ID:

```
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool');
```

Comment: yeah running that i definitely get a way longer session_id, obviously the php.ini method was not working. So can you set it in the config?

Comment: @Brian Perin - What I was trying to explain is that tou have to use a string; the array keys returned by hash_algos() are meaningless.

Comment: When I use `session.hash_function="whirlpool"` or `session.hash_function=whirlpool` in a phprc file it still shows in phpinfo as 0, even though hash_algos() shows whirlpool is available. I am using php 7.0.9

Comment: @pathfinder I don't have PHP/7 to test and cannot reproduce in PHP/5. Assuming your test is correct, it could be a bug in `phpinfo()` implementation.

Comment: @Ålavao - you could be right, but if I just use session.hash_function=1 then it does change in phpinfo. There is also a note that in php 7.1 that all these session hash function settings will be removed. I can't find any note or explanation about what replaces it though. So I just used the SHA1 and moved on.

Answer (score 2):

[hash_algos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) returns an array of Strings of all available algorithms and therefore is not suitable as argument for the ini-setting "session.hash-function". Just try to set your prefered algorithm as string instead of '0' or '1'.

Answer (score 2):

setting the hash function as a string works

```
session.hash_function = sha512
```